# Kusto - clone database

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I'm working on tests for my project, and for each test I want to initialize DB, all the tests contain the same data, so to avoid multiple requests for data creation, I want to create a dummy DB and clone the DB for each test.
There is a kusto query to clone DB? or to export the DB and import it as new DB?

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.